# CentOS 7 No package ... available

Tags: centos, yum, libraries

(CentOS 7 64 Bits) Following these steps: http://freevps.us/thread-2789.html I get errors, anyone can help me please?

STEP 2, running this command

```
yum install libICE.so.6 libImlib.so.1 libORBit-2.so.0 libSM.so.6 libX11.so.6 libXext.so.6 libXft.so.2 libXinerama.so.1 libXrandr.so.2 libXrender.so.1 libart_lgpl_2.so.2 libatk-1.0.so.0 libbonobo-2.so.0 libbonobo-activation.so.4 libbonoboui-2.so.0 libcairo.so.2 libfontconfig.so.1 libfreetype.so.6 libgconf-2.so.4 libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 libgnome-2.so.0 libgnome-desktop-2.so.2 libgnome-keyring.so.0 libgnomecanvas-2.so.0 libgnomeui-2.so.0 libgnomevfs-2.so.0 libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 libpango-1.0.so.0 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 libstartup-notification-1.so.0 libungif.so.4 gtk+ libgdk-1.2.so.0 libglib-1.2.so.0 libgmodule-1.2.so.0 libgtk-1.2.so.0 libSDL-1.2.so.0 libX11.so.6 libasound.so.2 libbluetooth.so.2 libesd.so.0 vnc-server xterm
```

I get that:

```
No package libImlib.so.1 available.
No package libgnome-desktop-2.so.2 available.
No package gtk+ available.
No package libgdk-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libglib-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libgmodule-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libgtk-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libbluetooth.so.2 available.
No package libesd.so.0 available.
```

All log:

```
[root@srv39122 ~]# yum install libICE.so.6 libImlib.so.1 libORBit-2.so.0 libSM.so.6     libX11.so.6 libXext.so.6 libXft.so.2 libXinerama.so.1 libXrandr.so.2 libXrender.so.1 libart_lgpl_2.so.2 libatk-1.0.so.0 libbonobo-2.so.0 libbonobo-activation.so.4 libbonoboui-2.so.0 libcairo.so.2 libfontconfig.so.1 libfreetype.so.6 libgconf-2.so.4 libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 libgnome-2.so.0 libgnome-desktop-2.so.2 libgnome-keyring.so.0 libgnomecanvas-2.so.0 libgnomeui-2.so.0 libgnomevfs-2.so.0 libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 libpango-1.0.so.0 libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 libstartup-notification-1.so.0 libungif.so.4 gtk+ libgdk-1.2.so.0 libglib-1.2.so.0 libgmodule-1.2.so.0 libgtk-1.2.so.0 libSDL-1.2.so.0 libX11.so.6 libasound.so.2 libbluetooth.so.2 libesd.so.0 vnc-server xterm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.plusline.de
 * extras: ftp.plusline.de
 * updates: ftp.plusline.de
Package libICE-1.0.8-7.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
No package libImlib.so.1 available.
Package ORBit2-2.14.19-13.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libSM-1.2.1-7.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libXext-1.3.2-2.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libXft-2.3.1-5.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libXinerama-1.1.3-2.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libXrandr-1.4.1-2.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libXrender-0.9.8-2.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libart_lgpl-2.3.21-9.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package atk-2.8.0-4.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libbonobo-2.32.1-7.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libbonobo-2.32.1-7.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libbonoboui-2.24.5-7.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package cairo-1.12.14-6.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package freetype-2.4.11-9.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package GConf2-3.2.6-8.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.i686 already installed and latest version
Package gdk-pixbuf2-2.28.2-4.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libgnome-2.32.1-9.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
No package libgnome-desktop-2.so.2 available.
Package libgnome-keyring-3.8.0-3.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libgnomecanvas-2.30.3-8.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libgnomeui-2.24.5-8.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package gnome-vfs2-2.24.4-14.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package gtk2-2.24.22-5.el7_0.1.i686 already installed and latest version
Package pango-1.34.1-5.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package pango-1.34.1-5.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package pango-1.34.1-5.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package startup-notification-0.12-8.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package giflib-4.1.6-9.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
No package gtk+ available.
No package libgdk-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libglib-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libgmodule-1.2.so.0 available.
No package libgtk-1.2.so.0 available.
Package SDL-1.2.15-11.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package libX11-1.6.0-2.1.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Package alsa-lib-1.0.27.2-3.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
No package libbluetooth.so.2 available.
No package libesd.so.0 available.
Package tigervnc-server-module-1.2.80-0.30.20130314svn5065.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package xterm-295-3.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 4):

So, I looked at your package list, and only two, `vnc-server` and `xterm` are actually yum packages (e.g. RPMs). The rest are libraries, and (unfortunately) you cannot install files and libraries by listing them out like that (would be nice, though).

However, there is an easy yum command you will have to run on each file/library, and you may find many are contained in the same packages.  For the first file as an example:

`yum provides */libICE.so.6`

This will list which packages contain that file.

As per your link, however, it looks like you want icewm.  One way to install it is this way:

`yum install icewm icewm-xdgmenu icewm-clearlooks`

But, to dig deeper, it looks like you are trying to use Linux PC/Server to connect to a Windows PC/Server?  This opens up a lot of possibilities (like virtualizing your Windows environment inside your Linux box) that I absolutely won't cover here.

Yet, to stick with the task at hand, there are even more awesome yum commands.  For instance, I'd probably start with installing the entire gnome desktop, in which case you could run:

`yum groupinstall "Desktop Platform"`

This will get you a working X GUI desktop environment that might even work better than icewm.  You can then follow-up with the specific components, like the vnc (client) or RDP client, as needed, to get a session on your Windows PC/Server.